# Class in C (not C++)

Tags: c, class, oop

I've discovered this hack in a website in Spanish (http://trucosinformaticos.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/programacion-orientado-a-objetos-en-c/).

I want create a "class" in C (not C++), but when I compile, I obtain the next errors:

```
source.c(25): warning C4047: 'function' : 'Car' differs in levels of indirection from 'Car *'
source.c(25): warning C4024: 'changeYears' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
```

This is my code:

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Car* Car;

// class Car
// {
        struct Car
        {
            int years;
            //char model[100];
        };


        void changeYears(Car this, int years)
        {
            this->years = years;
        }
// }


int main(void)
{
    Car my_cars[10];
    //nombrar(mis_alumnos[0], "Pepito");
    changeYears(&my_cars[0], 6); // My car has now 6 years

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've made your code massively confusing by hiding a pointer behind a typedef. I would suggest not doing that.

Comment: [project for "OO in C"](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf)

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing am existing one.

Comment: Just remember to link back to this one for context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would agree with @Oli Charlesworth that hiding a pointer behind a `typedef` is a very easy way to confuse yourself and others.

However, to make your code compile and work, you can just remove the `&` operator in front of `my_cars`. You also need to allocate memory for those pointers. I would say the reason why you made this mistake in the first place was that you confused yourself with the pointer hiding.

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Car* Car;

struct Car
{
    int years;
    //char model[100];
};


void changeYears(Car this, int years)
{
    this->years = years;
}


int main(void)
{
    // An array of struct char*
    Car my_cars[10];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        my_cars[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Car));
    changeYears(my_cars[0], 6); // My car has now 6 years

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more reasonable way to implement this without hiding pointers.

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int years;
    //char model[100];
} Car;


void changeYears(Car* this, int years)
{
    this->years = years;
}


int main(void)
{
    Car my_cars[10];
    changeYears(&my_cars[0], 6); // My car has now 6 years
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. See my edited post, please, see my new question about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

*(A much cleaner implementation, of what you want)*

***CODE:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int years;

} Car;


void changeYears(Car *this, int years)
{
    this->years = years;
}


int main(void)
{
    Car *car = malloc(sizeof(Car));
    changeYears(car, 2014);

    printf("car.years = %d\n", car->years);

    free(car);
    return 0;
}
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
car.year = 2014
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some advantage for use this code? See the code of @merlin2011

Comment: Mine is using dynamic memory allocation to create a single car "object", while his is using your method in the second example he showed. (In the first example he creates an array of pointers to multiple "object"s, but I don't think that's what you want)

Comment: Then your source and the merlin2011's source use the same memory, no? Thanks.

Comment: If you mean by "the same memory" as zeros and ones, or as the same physical device, then yes:) Other then that, afaik his statically allocated memory will be stored on the stack, while, mine is on the heap.

Comment: Nope, it all depends, on what you want. In the case of this tiny short snippet you and us provided it truly doesn't matter. However, if you build a large project, with several function calls (nested ones) it does matter where you store your data. Will the data be available after a function returned to it's caller? Is it important to be available?