# Using memcpy with a structure field

Tags: c, structure, memcpy

I was creating this *class* in C (see [Class in C (not C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843046/class-in-c-not-c)), and I want do this:

```
void assignModel(Car *this, char *model)
{
    // Is a string, so I need null all the space
    memcpy(this->model, '\0', sizeof(this->model)); // Error in execution time
    strncpy(this->model, model, strlen(model)); // Yes, it's insecure :)
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `memset`, not `memcpy`. And I can think of several ways better to do this than the approach taken here, particularly since the latter is not only insecure, its such because the target buffer size is utterly avoided, apparently *on purpose*.

Comment: Note that this causes a buffer overflow if `strlen(model) > sizeof this->model`, and it does not generate a null-terminated string in the case of equality.

Comment: `this->model` is an array, right?

Answer (score 2):

[`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html) expects the second parameter to point to a place in memory from which you want to take the data. `'\0'` does not point to memory: when it is converted to `void*`, it becomes `NULL`. Dereferencing `NULL` causes undefined behavior, hence the execution-time error that you see.

If you want to set zeros into a specific field, use [`memset`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memset.html) instead of `memcpy`:

```
memset(this->model, 0, sizeof(this->model)); // this->model is an array
```

However, filling the array with zeros is unnecessary in your situation: if you copy the string properly, you wouldn't have to fill with zeros to obtain a terminator. Here is the problem - when you do this,

```
strncpy(this->model, model, strlen(model));
```

null terminator is *not* written into `this->model` array, leaving the string unterminated. Your code used to "compensate" for this shortcoming by pre-filling the array with zeros. However, this would leave the string unterminated when `strlen(model)` is the same as the total number of characters that you can write into `this->model` array.

To fix this problem, I would use [`strlcpy`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlcpy/) if your system provides it (be careful - it is not part of the C standard).

```
strlcpy(this->model, model, sizeof(this->model));
```

If your system does not have it, you can emulate its effect as follows:

```
int len = min(sizeof(this->model)-1, strlen(model));
memcpy(this->model, model, len);
this->model[len] = '\0';
```

**EDIT :** Thanks to everybody who commented on this!

Comment: not sure why someone downvoted this (although I'd prefer to see the idiom `memset(&x, 0, sizeof x)` - this is usable on any object, whereas `memset(a, o, sizeof a)` is only correct iff `a` is an array)

Comment: The "secure" memcpy version of this will invoke UB if `sizeof(this->model)` is *larger* than the allowed readable region of `model`. (and no, I didn't DV this either. dunno who did).

Comment: OOOOhhh, 0h, 0h 0h ... ;-) @MattMcNabb

Comment: @self. Mind being more specific?

Comment: You are assuming this->model holds an address, what value will sizeof( this->model ) give.

Comment: @self. Your assumption over what I assume cannot be further from the truth: `this->model` is, of course, **an array**.

Comment: @self. I know that from the lack of `malloc`s in OP's post, and from the fact that he's trying to zero it out. This leaves very little space for a doubt that it's an array, not a pointer. He'll confirm it shortly, though :-)

Comment: @self das's code is correct if `this->model` is an array. OP hasn't told us what it is for certain, so IMHO it's off base for you to be calling him "wrong"

Comment: @dasblinkenlight heh. nice code-comment. There is a place for `strncpy`, and it is if all you care about is stuffing as much into a target buffer from a source as you can get, *with truncation being an option*. If that is the case, then your `memcpy` becomes `strncpy` and your last param has one-subtracted just as the line below it, keeping that line as-is. (All of this assuming this problem's target is an array, which I lean heavily in your favor on, btw. I think it is as well, and see no evidence to the contrary). Good times.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I carefully worded my comment to call wrong only his assumption of my assumption (of which I have full knowledge, because after all it's my assumption), not his assumption that `this->model` is a pointer :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "Also using strlen(model) as a limit in strncpy is the same as calling strcpy" - not true; `strcpy` writes the null terminator, whereas this use of `strncpy` always omits it

Comment: @MattMcNabb that isn't true. It only omits it if the source length is equal-to or larger than the proclaimed target buffer size. It would always omit it in *this specific case* because the proclaimed target buffer size is that very value (the string length). `strncpy` *always* writes N chars (the third param). If the source is shorter, it tail-fills 0's to N, if the source is *equal-or-longer* it only dump N and does not terminate.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and when you give `strlen(src)` as the size of the output, there is never any space for it

Comment: Why in "this->model[sizeof(this->model)-1] = '\0';" you put -1? -1 isn't the latest space, no?

Comment: @WhozCraig by "this use of strncpy", I mean "using strlen(model) as the buffer size"

Comment: @MattMcNabb which would be why the Op apparently thought dumping the target buffer full of zeros was the way to "fix" that. (which rewinds back to my very first comment in general-comment below the question, btw).

Comment: I'm pointing out that dasblinkenlight's suggestion of replacing the `strncpy` with a `strcpy` causes a buffer overflow where previously there was none, in the case where `strlen(model) == sizeof this->model`

Comment: @MattMcNabb ok. yeah, if the target size claim is `strlen(src)`, its completely pointless, I concur.

Comment: @user3602030 Yes, that's the last spot in the string (and it is also the last location where we can write without causing undefined behavior). The logic here is that if there's a zero before `sizeof(...)` it would be copied; otherwise, it would be inserted.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight *exactly*. swatting a fly with a sledge. As a said awhile ago, if properly used in the context of *purposely allowing data truncation* (which I *think* was a goal of that code, but I fully admit its a pretty anorexic argument to draw that), `strncpy` actually has merit (and in fact, its the *only* time it does), so long as it is followed by hard setting the *last* char in the target buffer to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way to do what (I think) you want to do:

```
void assignModel(Car * const this, const char * const model)
{
    snprintf(this->model, sizeof(this->model), "%s", model);
}
```

This has a few advantages:

- It won't overrun the destination (unlike `strcpy()`)
- If the source string is too long, the result is truncated, BUT (unlike `strncpy())` it still has the '\0' terminator.
- It avoids the unnecessary `memset()`.
- It avoids the unnecessary `strlen()`.
- I added some `const` so the compiler will catch some silly mistakes, like mixing up the source and destination.

In most cases,
    `snprintf(foo, sizeof(foo), ...)`
has nicer behavior than either `strcpy()` or `strncpy()`.